# Firefox Lightbeam completely blank

Tags: windows, firefox, cookies

Using the Lightbeam addon with Firefox 24.0 under Windows XP and Windows 7, the Lightbeam tab is always completely blank.  It indicates in a top bar that I have visited x sites and y third party sites but there is no graph, no clock and no list of what those sites are.

I have found no information to cover this on the Mozilla site.

Is this common?  Is there some configuration setting that I need to change?

I normally use Adblock Plus but I have removed that in case it was the problem.  Removal made no difference.

EDIT - additional information

It appears that this is a very common problem:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightbeam/reviews/

Comment: What other privacy extensions do you use?

Comment: I remember using a similar plugin a while ago and surprise: I had to enable cookies (default blocked in my configuration) which was very obvious afterwards. Maybe that could also be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried installing Lightbeam in a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_creating-a-profile)??

[Profile Manager](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager)